# Is a "dynamic" object reference in JavaScript based on some parents property name possible?

Tags: javascript, pointers, reference

Very sure this is a duplicate but I don't really know what to search for. So please bear with me...

In the example below it looks like `childRef` points to the original object assigned to `someParentObj.someChildObj` and therefore when `someParentObj.someChildObj` is assigend to a new object, `childRef` still references the original object.

Is there a way to assign `childRef` so that it will reflect the new object as soon as it is assigned to `someParentObj.someChildObj`? (I ask this mainly out of curiosity but in some occasions it could allow shorter code and come in handy.)

```
var someParentObj = {
    someChildObj: {originalChildProp: ['some', 'array']}
};

window.parentRef = someParentObj;
window.childRef = someParentObj.someChildObj;

someParentObj.someChildObj = {differentChildProp: ['other', 'array']}


console.log(parentRef.someChildObj)
// Output: {differentChildProp: Array(2)}

console.log(childRef) 
// Output: {originalChildProp: Array(2)} but I would like to have the new/different
// object on parentRef.someChildObj. Is it possible?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option that can work *in this particular situation*, because you want to assign to a property of `window`, is to make `window.childRef` a *getter* that returns `someParentObj.someChildObj`:

```js
var someParentObj = {
    someChildObj: {originalChildProp: ['some', 'array']}
};

window.parentRef = someParentObj;
Object.defineProperty(window, 'childRef', { get() { return someParentObj.someChildObj }});

someParentObj.someChildObj = {differentChildProp: ['other', 'array']}

console.log(parentRef.someChildObj)
console.log(childRef)
```

If you *weren't* assigning to a property of an object, eg if `childRef` was a standalone block-scoped variable not on the global object, this wouldn't be possible. So, if you want to use this sort of pattern, always use an object.

You could also use a Proxy if you can manipulate the base object reference (eg, if you weren't working with `window`), which can accomplish basically the same thing, but it's more complicated and less supported.